# When i type in IE 11 "http://localhost:8080/SignalR" is not working and giving a HTTP400

Tags: localhost, signalr, webclient

I'm trying  a SelfHosted SignalR WebServer program.

Complete code is as listed below.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using Owin;

namespace SignalRSelfHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // This will *ONLY* bind to localhost, if you want to bind to all addresses
            // use http://*:8080 to bind to all addresses. 
            // See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx 
            // for more information.
            string url = "http://localhost:8080";
            using (WebApp.Start(url))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
    class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
    }
```

I'm trying to connect to webserver by typing the following IP address in Ineternet Explorer Version 11.0

*http://localhost:8080/SignalR*

But it's not able to connect and giving me HTTP 400 Error.

I've tried changing url = "http://*:8080" in the server program , but still that didn't help.

Can you please help me solve this issue?

Comment: What are you expecting to get back in the browser? Have you implemented a client? If you're using the proxy then expect its output at `http://localhost:8080/signalr/hubs`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a client to connect to the server. When you request http://localhost:8080/SignalR you basically request a static file. Your self hosted server is not configured to serve static files hence the error. 
If you just want to see if the server is running correctly you can request `http://localhost:8080/SignalR/negotiate` which is the first request a SignalR client would send. If the server is up and running you should get a response containing SignalR negotiation response in JSon format.